# Django celery always returns false when checking if data is ready

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have setup Django with Celery running with rabbitmq.

I have implemented following example in my project: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

When i run a simple test in two terminal windows the results are as following:

```
# Terminal 1
>>> from Exercise.tasks import *
>>> result = add.delay(2,3)
>>> result
<AsyncResult: e6c92297-eea2-4f99-8902-1446ac74a6bb>
>>> result.ready()
False

# Terminal 2
$ celery -A Website3 worker -l info
[2014-10-02 14:39:59,269: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: Exercise.tasks.add[464249dd-ab89-4099-badd-9190a147310f]
[2014-10-02 14:39:59,271: INFO/MainProcess] Task Exercise.tasks.add[464249dd-ab89-4099-badd-9190a147310f] succeeded in 0.0010875929147s: 5
```

Obviously the data is completed, but i am not able to receive this data.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have your result backend set up properly? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings

Celery needs this set up properly to store state and results of async tasks.